# Visitor can't access a copied seattle.master page

Tags: permissions, master-page, custom-masterpage, html

I need to insert a few lines of HTML code into the seattle.master file, but I don't actually want to edit the seattle.master file. So I copied the same file, inserted the code and set the copied file as the default master page.

After that everything went well for me as an owner, but the visitor can't access the website. I compared the permissions between these two files and everything is the same, but the visitors still can't access the site. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit the master page and reflect your changes you should publish it as `a major version` as the following:

- Check out the HTML file,
- Right click -> Edit in advanced mode -> Edit your page ->
- Save -> Right click Check-in -> Publish As Major version ->

[image]

- That will open your master page gallery -> right click and select publish.

[image]

- Go to Site Setting -> Look and Feel -> Master Page -> make sure the master page assigned is the same master page that has been edited

Now the visitors' users should see your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **publish the Master page**.
Because, if you edited the Master Page then you can see the changes, but other users can't still you publish the Master Page.
After Publishing the master page **your Visitor/Anonymous user can see the changes whatever you have made.
Hope it will help!